# How do I upgrade my python installation, and pip?

Tags: apt, python

On my Ubuntu server, Python 3.8 and 2-something is installed.

I want to upgrade to Python 3.10, and I installed it from a ppa. But 3.8 is still installed, and `pip --version` shows `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

I tried running a script with this command: `python3.10 myscript.py` but this fails because this script is using the `websockets` package. If I run `pip install websockets` it says that it is already installed. But it isn't installed for Python 3.10, only 3.8.

So in short: How do I upgrade to Python and pip to version 3.10?

EDIT: these are the commands I used to upgrade Python to 3.10

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.10
```

Comment: Several Ubuntu packages rely on python.  If you change the installed version, you can break your system. Instead, set up a python environment that will not mess up your entire Ubuntu installation

Comment: I agree with @Nmath . Creating virtualenv is safer option.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. This is what I ended up doing, and using an updated version if Python in a virtual env solved the issue I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two options

- Changing ubuntu's python3:

  `sudo mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3_backup & sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3`
- Creating a virtualenv and use that env

  `python3.10 -m venv venv_folder
  source venv_folder/bin/activate
  pip ..
  python ..`

After finished your job with this env, you can just type `deactivate` and venv will close.

**Second method is a workaround solution**.

Comment: Your answer solved my initial issue, but it doesn't really answer my SO question. Best I can give you is an upvote. Thank you though!

Comment: Can you try python3.10 -m pip install websockets ?
I will also try something else after that, i'll edit this comment.

Comment: `python3.10 -m pip install websockets` gave me `ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)`

Comment: @birgersp I found a solution. Changing name or deleting /usr/bin/python3 and creating symlink to python3.10 updates pip's python.
sudo mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3_backup & sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
If it's work for you, i can change my answer.

Comment: Seems to be working!

Comment: Ok super, i edited answer.